# Simulating screen touches with key presses on iPad

Tags: keyboard, ipad, accessibility, ipados, touchscreen

I would like to know if it's possible to simulate a screen tap with key presses from a Bluetooth keyboard on an iPad. Kind of like Bluestacks does it. I wouldn't mind it being an app from the App Store.

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you could use Type2Phone app?

Answer (score 0):

Until continuity enabled [Universal Control comes out this spring with iPadOS and macOS updates](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/101?time=4953), you won’t have a good option for gaming on iPadOS. You may love the new features once they ship for this use case.

- https://www.apple.com/macos/continuity/

You may need to connect an external device and also choose which multitouch and button functionality you care to manage. I’m not aware of an app that fakes all this out, but most of what you need is already baked into the OS for accessibility needs.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202658
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210546

This lets eye control, voice control, braille devices and emulation work to bridge the gap between touch and devices or work when direct touch is not possible.

Comment: I wanted it for playing games with a keyboard...

Comment: You will love the universal keyboard then if you have a Mac and an iPad.

Comment: What's the universal keyboard?

Comment: Sorry the correct term is universal control - watch it here for about three minutes of demo - https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/101?time=4953